# Using Feeds to import data

Tags: entities, nodes, feeds

In order to import data from a CSV file, I would like to use Feeds. I followed an example from the Drupal Cookbook, and it uses the Basic Page content type.

Because the data I would like to import has unique data, could you please confirm if I will need to create a new content type with its own fields so I can map map the source to target? I would just like to make sure what I am attempting to do is correct to avoid corrupting the database...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feeds: How to import images using CSV Node Import?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/feeds-how-to-import-images-using-csv-node-import)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are different data that you would like to store from your csv, you should create your own content type, add required fields there.

Then in create your feeds importer, set the required settings(like selecting your content type), set mappings and let feeds do its magic(yep, its an awesome module!)

Fees is a great module where you have to import data into nodes, users or taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you @SGhosh Do I by any chance also need a Data and Schema modules as well? I am not importing pages/articles/images or anything like that, the data in my csv file is very simple, and I just want to import it in order to be able to search for it by a couple of different fields. I don't want the data to be displayed anywhere else apart from the search results table. If that makes sense.

Comment: @user12885 - Actually I have never used Data and Schema modules. But from what I understand, creating nodes will fulfil your requirement to show results in search. And feeds module will make importing data from csv into nodes a smooth affair. But yes, you need to create your custom content type http://drupal.org/node/306792, so you can have as many and as specific fields per your need. Install Feeds, play around with it a bit, you will understand what settings you require. Google around a bit, watch videos, tutorials, the time will be worth spending!

Comment: Thank you for that. Re: Fees is a great module where you have to import data into nodes, users or taxonomy.

Will this create a node/page for each row entry? Because I don't want each table entry to have its own page, if that makes sense...

Comment: @user12885 - well, yes, each set of data = each row, will create a new node. What do you think is a problem in having a node for each row?

Comment: Will each node be accessible via an individual url? If so, is this ok? Will people be able to get to it?

Comment: @user12885 - yes each node will have its own link, but in the permissions page - admin/people/permissions - you can select which content type can be created, edited, deleted by which roles but not view. And you could use the module - http://drupal.org/project/content_access - to specify custom view settings for content. But you say these data should be available when user uses search, what exactly are you trying to achieve here, I think people will be able to help you better then.

Comment: @user12885 - besides users should not be just going to a url if it is not provided in the site.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I am still trying to get around the concept of nodes being pages, but I guess as long as they don't show up in the sitemap it's ok? I just don't see any value in people being able to figure out the node pattern and stumbling upon the records...

Comment: @user12885 - nodes will always have their own urls, and an user might 'stumble upon' a node url but you could use the rules module to redirect them somewhere else if they do access a node url(or write your own code if rules doesn't work out). Or you could use this module - drupal.org/project/content_access - using which you can prevent access of nodes by specific user roles(say, all except admin), in which case users will get access denied on those urls.

Comment: Sorry, another question @SGhosh
Is there a way from disabling the nodes created by the Feeds module to be searchable through google for example?